# Does Amazon SES require MX record for sending email?

Tags: amazon-ses

I receive mail on a domain at Zoho Mail. I send some automated emails from Amazon SES.

Is there any reason to setup an MX record for Amazon SES if I only send email from there? Perhaps for anti-spam purposes or something else?

I can find articles on Google about using the MX record for email receiving:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-mx-record.html

I can't find anything categorically saying I don't need an MX record if I'm only sending emails from Amazon and the instructions on the Amazon website were vague.

Thanks.

EDIT

Also Amazon suggested setting it up as priority 10, which makes it the joint highest (lower numbers being higher priority) priority. Perhaps lowering that would be fine / a good idea?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. According to the documentation an MX record is required to handle incoming mail

> To have Amazon SES manage your incoming email, you need to add an MX record to your domain's DNS configuration.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-mx-record.html

Comment: To qualify my posting, you need to add an A record AND contact amazon. They're really spotty about the ban removal. Sometimes they'll take 2 days, sometimes 2 weeks.

Comment: Interesting, I'm sending via the SES API from an external website (same as the A record) not hosted on EC2, not sure if this is relevant?

Comment: Nope! It just means you don't have to deal with AWS's tech team! Congrats! Also, just to clarify the issue you're having, are your emails getting dropped due to them having a spam like profile?

Comment: I haven't seen evidence of that. But Zoho Mail emailed me saying the DNS was 'setup wrong' and implying that I may lose emails.

Comment: Regarding sent emails going to spam, I haven't ramped up sending on this email address yet, so not sure.

Comment: Hey niico, I looked around on the AWS documentation and found this article. I've added it to my answer.

It states that AWS requires an MX record to your mail server in order to handle SES properly.

I guess I never hit this issue since I'd always do it out of habit 

Comment: Thanks, I have no requirement to RECEIVE mail at Amazon though, only send. Email is received at Zoho Mail.